# Does firefox give any visibility whatsoever about executed code?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to debug some javascript and I had an unpleasant surprise.

I'm using firefox debugger, and it seems that nowhere can I see which javascript functions are getting executed.

If I drag and drop an image to a page, for example, some javascript functions are called. But I am not able to see exactly what is happening in any part of the debugger.

I mean, I can see all the javascript code, all the functions which are defined, etc. But I cannot see which ones are actually being called, which ones are calling which ones, and so on.

Am I missing something, or has the user really no real-time access to the javascript code the browser is executing?

Comment: If you want an overview of all executed code, see the Performance tab of the devtools. For anything more specific you'll have to show some actual code.

Comment: I noticed the perfomance tab has a list of called functions. But it's purpose is analysing performance, not debuging. I was looking for something like a call stack.

Comment: I mean, my question is not code-dependent. Firefox, internally, has to execute javascript, and it needs some kind of call stack. Each asynchronous thread must have a list of called and caller functions. These lists should be available to the user of the browser, both for debugging and for security. I want to be able to know exactly what my browser is doing.

Comment: The performance tab includes all of that information.

Comment: Got it, you are right. Not the best interface though... But yeah, the information seems to be there.